# GWT i18n - Plural Forms doesn't work at all?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt2

I'm using GWT internationalization Messages. The [documentation for Plural Forms](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nPluralForms.html) says this should work:

```
@DefaultMessage("{0} {1,number} hours {2}")
@PluralText({"one", "an hour"})
String hours(String prefix, @PluralCount int count, String suffix);
```

Well, it doesn't. Whatever value of `count` it still delivers `DefaultMessage` (e.g. "1 hours ago"). Same if I use a .properties file:

```
hours[one]=an hour
hours[few]=some hours
hours={0} {1,number} hours {2}
```

Is there a bug in the docs or in GWT (I'm using GWT 2.0.3) or in me? If any of the two former, anyone knows of a workaround?

**EDIT**: More clues to this mystery. I can get plural handling to work if I don't rely on default locale handling. That is, I need:

- In my module's gwt.xml file:

  `<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>`
- In my Messages extentsion:

  `@DefaultLocale("en")`

  `public interface MyMessages extends Messages { ...`
- Explicitly load the "en" locale by appending to the URL

  `&locale=en`

See http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/80ae300213cc6adb where I have cross posted this question.

**EDIT 2:** The reason I entered this GWT plurals land is that I'm creating a "GWT HUman Readable Relative Timestamps" module. Open sourced at GitHub: http://github.com/PEZ/GWT-Relative-Time Please check it out. It'll very soon have correct singular forms and support for some languages. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Getting used to answering my own questions =) Here's cross post of my "answer" on the GWT Google group:*

There seems to be a bug with the default locale handling. Here's how I have reached that conclusion:

I wanted to add some locales to my module. Figured I could get a boiler plate for the properties file if I used the `@Generate` annotation. I noticed that it created both an `_en.properties` file and a `_default.properties`. What's more; the _`en` file completely lacked the plural form info! The _`default` file had them though.

I then moved the `_defaults` file to the same directory as my `TimeMessages.java` file and renamed it `TimeMessages_default.properties`.

With this in place I can remove `<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>` from my module's .gwt.xml file and, more important, the `&locale=en` from the URL when running my app. I still need the `@DefaultLocale("en")` annotation though, even though the documentation clearly states that this is not necessary.

In conclusion, if you run into this problem, try:

- generating properties files using `@Generate`
- place `YourMessages_default.properties` side by side with `YourMessages.java`
- prepend the YourMessages interface with a `@DefaultLocale("en")` annotation.

About that `@Generate`. This is what worked for me. Just before my extension of the Message interface:

```
@Generate(format = {"com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat"})
```

The GWT log said it created my properties file, but I couldn't find it. I fixed that by adding the compiler flag `-extra extras` and then found the properties files generated in the `extras` directory. Including this info here since I spent more than an hour figuring it out.

Answer (score 4):

Also I think it will save people time to know that the default English plural rule only supports `"other"` and `"one"`.

[DefaultRule_en.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/impl/plurals/DefaultRule_en.java) uses [DefaultRule_1_0n.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/impl/plurals/DefaultRule_1_0n.java)

So you have to redefine `DefaultRule_en.java` if you want to use `"none"`,`"two"`,`few"`...
You can see the available rules in the package [com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.plurals](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/impl/plurals/).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution from the gwt issue list [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5979):

You have to define the @DefaultLocale in the MyMessages.java:

```
@DefaultLocale("en")
public interface MyMessages extends Messages {
   public String items(@PluralCount @Optional int count);
}
```

and in MyMessages.properties:

```
items={0} items
items[one]=one item
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing I found is that you can define a fallback locale like this:
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/> in your module XML file